# How to install pgcrypto module on a postgres DB

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I have Postgres version 10.5 from the docker hub and don't know how to install the pgcrypto module. 
In **/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib#** there is a **pgcrypto.so** file.
What to do with that file? I can't find documentation about it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using PSQL or PgAdmin, connect to the DB and type

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually make sure to force SET search_path='required_schema'; (usually public). Otherwise "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;" command will install pgcrypto functions to the first schema in search path of the current user.